# Pointers using flag in go

Tags: go, pointers

I want to find out if the token is of type *string, then we get the value by reference. But then why do I need to dereference the token again if it has already been dereferenced?

```
func mustToken() string {

    token := flag.String("t", "", "token for access to tg bot")

    flag.Parse()

    if *token == "" {
        log.Fatal("token isnt specified")
    }
    return *token
}
```

I tried to google, but didnt understand tbh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what happens in the program above:

1. The call to flag.String allocates a `string` variable and registers that variable, the name and default with the flag set.  flag.String returns a pointer to the allocated variable.
2. The call to flag.Parse parses the command line and writes a value to the registered string variable.
3. The expression `*token` dereferences the pointer returned from flag.String to get the value of registered string variable.  The program uses the expression  `*token` twice because the program accesses the value twice.

Answer (score 2):

In Go, when you define a `string` variable it defaults to `""`.
When you're parsing data from input, if you don't use a pointer you'll get an empty string if the user didn't provide a value, or provided `""` explicitly.

If the user specify `--token ""`,  or not specifying the flag at all,  both results in `token = ""`.

While using a pointer, if the user didn't provide the flag the value of `token` will be `nil`. So you *know* if the user provided the flag or not.

Comment: But flag.String() already returns the dereferenced value, why derefer it again? We do not get a new value in the token, but simply compare whether there is a value there or not.

Comment: I mean, if we didn't specify the token in input, then we will get the nil value in the token. And it would make sense to just compare token == nil, but for some reason it needs to be dereferenced again.

Comment: flag.String always returns a non-nil pointer.  `token` will never equal `nil`.

Comment: I see, thanks. If I don't use pointers, I quickly forget how they work and what they mean.